# sorting of adjacent segments using a element in the xml message with XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt

I am new to the XSLT. I need help in achieving the below output. I will explain my requirement using the below example:

**Input:**

```
<library>
<Name>aaaaa</Name>
<Street>wwww</Street>
<Country>qqqq</Country>
<stock>
    <book>
        <Details>
            <Ranking>3</Ranking>
            <Title>abc3</Title>
            <Author>hhhhh3</Author>
        </Details>
    </book>
    <book>
        <Details>
            <Ranking>2</Ranking>
            <Title>abc2</Title>
            <Author>hhhhh2</Author>
        </Details>
    </book>
    <book>
        <Details>
            <Ranking>1</Ranking>
            <Title>abc1</Title>
            <Author>hhhhh1</Author>
        </Details>
    </book>
    <book>
        <Details>
            <Ranking>4</Ranking>
            <Title>abc4</Title>
            <Author>hhhhh4</Author>
        </Details>
    </book>
</stock>
```

**Output:**

```
  <library>
    <Name>aaaaa</Name>
    <Street>wwww</Street>
    <Country>qqqq</Country>
<stock>
    <book>
        <Details>
            <Ranking>1</Ranking>
            <Title>abc1</Title>
            <Author>hhhhh1</Author>
        </Details>
    </book>
    <book>
        <Details>
            <Ranking>2</Ranking>
            <Title>abc2</Title>
            <Author>hhhhh2</Author>
        </Details>
    </book>
    <book>
        <Details>
            <Ranking>3</Ranking>
            <Title>abc3</Title>
            <Author>hhhhh3</Author>
        </Details>
    </book>
    <book>
        <Details>
            <Ranking>4</Ranking>
            <Title>abc4</Title>
            <Author>hhhhh4</Author>
        </Details>
    </book>
</stock>
```

The "book" segments need to be sorted in ascending order based on the "Ranking" using XSLT 1.0.

I tried sort function, but works if all the "Details" are in one "book". I tried lot of other things but no successes. Can someone please help me ?

Comment: Paging Dimitre Novatchev...

Answer (score 0):

It is always a good practice to share the XSLT that has been tried to achieve the desired results. This helps the solution providers to just fix the issue that you are facing instead of starting from scratch.

The following template will help you in sorting the `<book>` based on the `<Ranking>`.

```
<xsl:template match="stock">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="book">
            <xsl:sort select="Details/Ranking" data-type="number" order="ascending" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

In addition to the above template use the `identity transform` template to copy the input XML as is.

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hi Aniket, Thanks for your comment. I will make a note of that. I tried your logic as well. my input message is bit more complex, It has a some more elements, attributes between "book" and "Details" as well. When I ran the example input it works fine, except the elements, attributes between "book" and "Details" are not resulted in the output. When I apply the same logic to my message, I am get an empty tag. i.e. <Stock/>. The whole data is lost. I do not know what is going wrong.

Comment: Please edit the question and share the correct input XML.

Comment: @Bhaskar it sounds like you have simplified your problem but you don't know XSLT well enough to extrapolate the answers to your simplified problem to make them work with the original problem. That suggests to me that you need to spend a little more time reading about the language and understanding its concepts.

Comment: @ Michael Kay, When I used different XSLT parser it worked for my problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="stock">
        <xsl:copy>

                <xsl:for-each select="book">

                    <xsl:sort order="ascending" select="Details/Ranking"/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>

                </xsl:for-each>

        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
Try it
```

Comment: Thanks Imran, my input message is bit more complex, It has a some more elements, attributes between "book" and "Details" as well. When I ran the example input it works fine, except the elements, attributes between "book" and "Details" are not resulted in the output. When I apply the same logic to my message, I am get an empty tag. i.e. <G_SS10/>. The whole data is lost.

Comment: Give me your input file.

Comment: I know what is happening. I used a different XSLT parser and I am getting the output. How to get the elements and other attributes as well in the output which are in between "Stock" and "book" ?

Answer (score 0):

My friend had helped me in resolving the issue. Below code is the answer to my questions. Thanks to Imran and Aniket for responding.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- suppress all but the last node; see next template -->
    <xsl:template match="book[*]" /> 

    <!-- sort by package id -->
    <xsl:template match="book[last()]"> 
        <xsl:for-each select="../book">
            <xsl:sort order="ascending" select="Details/Ranking"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/> 
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```